# HighCharts - dynamic graph & no tick mark on the right hand side dual axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm new to high charts.

I'm dynamically making 2 ajax calls(inside getData() Function) and plotting the high chart with 2 series(with 2 y axis).

each ajax call with return the json data.

1st json data (sample)
[{"dt":"May 15, 2000","index":"2,007.030850"},{"dt":"May 16, 2000","index":"2,025.956108"}]

2nd json data (sample)
[{"dt":"May 15, 2000","nav":"145.236000"},{"dt":"May 16, 2000","nav":"146.602974"}]

I'm creating two series with 2 ajax calls. in the 2nd ajax call, i'm dynamically adding a y-axis for the 2nd series data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        function getData() {

            var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
/* 1st Ajax Call to get the json data to plot the first series */
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/Six/TSServlet?file=ivv-sixIshareFundsHistoryIndex.json',
                data: '',
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    var categories1 = [];
                    var seriesData1 = [];
                    var yaxis;
                    $.each(data, function(i, e) {
                        categories1.push(e.dt);
                        /* below step to remove , is not important, done for my program */
                        yaxis = parseFloat(e.index.replace(/,/g, '')); 
                        seriesData1.push(yaxis);
                    })
// add x-axis catagories
                    chart.xAxis[0].update({
                        categories: categories1,
                        tickInterval: 150
                    }, true);

    // add the 1st series
                    chart.series[0].setData(seriesData1);
                }
            });
               /* 2nd Ajax Call to get the json data to plot the second series */
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/Six/TSServlet?file=ivv-sixIshareFundsHistoryNav.json',
                data: '',
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    var categories2 = [];
                    var seriesData2 = [];
                    var yaxis;
                    $.each(data, function(i, e) {
                        categories2.push(e.dt);
                        /* below step to remove , is not important, done for my program */

                        yaxis = parseFloat(e.nav.replace(/,/g, ''));
                        seriesData2.push(yaxis);
                    })
```

/* This is the problem area, dynamically adding a dual y axis for the 2nd series */

```
                     chart.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis
                        id: 'NAV-Series-Axis',
                        title: {
                            text: 'NAV Series'
                        },
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        lineColor: '#08F',
                        opposite: true
                    });
```

// add the 2nd series
                  chart.addSeries({name: "NAV Series",yAxis: 'NAV-Series-Axis',data: seriesData2});

```
                }
            });
        }  //getdata function ends here .............

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                renderTo: 'container',
                events: {
                    load: function() {
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        getData();
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Six Share Funds History'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value + ' %';
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                tickLength: 10
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + '<br/>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                "Name": []
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

My issue is i'm getting 2 axis for 2 series graph, but no tick marks on the right hand side y-axis. how to solve this issue? ideally i should see 100(one tick mark), 200 (one tick mark) etc on the right hand side blue bar(just like left hand side y-axis has 500,1000 etc)

Please see the screen shot, i dont see the tick marks on the right hand side blue bar (for the 2nd series graph)

[image]

Edited to add jsp:

```
<div id='TimeSeriesId'>
        <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see where you are defining your chart width in the DIV. My guess would be that the tick marks are there just off screen. What happens if you set your width of your chart smaller than the container DIV? Does it show then?

Comment: @wergeld You are Awesome. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction. As you pointed out, i've checked in dev tools of IE and found that is is painting, but tick marks are just off the screen. After removing the "marginRight: 10," from my javascript code, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add several Y-axes simply by making yAxis an array with more than 1 element. Each can have all of the usual axis attributes (see [highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis)).

```
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: { ...
        },
        title: { ...
        },
        opposite: true
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: { ...
        },
        labels: { ...
        }
    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
        title: { ...
        },
        labels: { ...
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    ...
```

To dynamically add them, use `chart.yAxis = new Array(); chart.yAxis[1].title = ...` etc.